# Is there any good MVC/MVP frameworks or other application frameworks for .NET Winforms?

Tags: .net, winforms, frameworks

I'm not sure why finding any frameworks or good example projects for developing windows application is so difficult. I'm sure that for web application framework, we have Castle Project or ASP.NET MVC that are very great stuffs and have many examples that follow the best practices like IoC, Caching, and etc.

Is there such things that have already existed for Winforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Smart Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx) from MS uses MVP patterns.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, [MVC#](http://www.mvcsharp.org/) if one of the best framework for developping Winforms applications. Getting the hang of the framework require a little time, but once you have understand how MVC# works, it's a kid's stuff.

To start with MVC#, look at examples provided: http://www.mvcsharp.org/Examples.aspx (this is one of the strengths of the framework!)

Answer (score 0):

[MVC#](http://mvcsharp.org/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Claymore](http://claymore.codeplex.com/); I've tried to build it to be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Magellan](http://code.google.com/p/magellan-framework/) framework by [Paul Stovell](http://www.paulstovell.com/blog).  The Winform specifics are [here](http://code.google.com/p/magellan-framework/wiki/WinForms).

Answer (score 0):

Try WPF if you haven't already. It uses XAML for layout and that uses MVVM. It's really easy to use imo, and creates good separation. I'm assuming you're using traditional WebForms?